# Swift JSON encode & Decode

Tags: swift

I am trying to return JSON to completion:

```
func getNowPlayingView(completion: @escaping ([NowPlayingData]) -> ()) {
         
        
        
        let podcast = try! JSONDecoder().decode(MusicPlayer.NowPlayingData.self, from: Data(MusicPlayer.JN.utf8))
      
                       //print(data!)
                      // let episode = podcast.programs
                      DispatchQueue.main.async{
                          // The array is stored under programs now
                       
                        completion(podcast)
                      }
         
    }
```

However on `completion(podcast)` I am getting `Cannot convert value of type 'MusicPlayer.NowPlayingData' to expected argument type '[MusicPlayer.NowPlayingData]'`

```
struct NowPlayingData: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var artist : String
    var song : String
    var cover : String
}
```

Here is what I have working

You can see in screen shot it is sending the JSON string to the view.

[image: add image]

the code to do that is

```
func getNowPlayingView(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void){
         
        
        
      
           completion(MusicPlayer.JN)
     
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Changed code slightly to reflect  vadian comments and my view has gone crazy

[image: MediaPLAYER VIEW]

```
struct MediaPlayerView: View {
    @State private var uuid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
    @State private var playingtye = ""
    @State var NowPlayingInfo: [MusicPlayer.NowPlayingData]
    
    
    
    
    
    @State private var playing = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(String(uuid!))
            Text(playingtye)
            Text(NowPlayingInfo.first!.artist)
            Text(playing)
        }
            .onAppear{
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: true) { (timer) in
                       // do stuff 42 seconds later
                                    MusicPlayer().gettype { type in
                                       self.playingtye = type
                                   }
                                    MusicPlayer().getNowPlayingView { (podcast) in
                                        self.NowPlayingInfo = podcast
                                    }
                   }
               
                
                if(MusicPlayer.shared.player!.rate != 0)
                {
                    self.playing = "yes"
                }
                else
                {
                    self.playing = "no"
                }
        }
          
    }
}
```

Comment: You decode a single object and the closure parameter type is an array. That's a classic type mismatch as the error clearly states.

Comment: So How do you send a single object

Comment: Change the closure type to  `(NowPlayingData)->()`.

Comment: @vadian Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Data'

Comment: vadian meant the code at the top of your question

Comment: @vadian changed that and now media view is playing up

Comment: First of all I wrote my comments **before** your edit and secondly please learn to read error messages. A type mismatch is a very basic and very comprehensible error.